# how to pass a response to parent component from service provider component of angular4 (ionic3), i got undefined value?

Tags: angular, post, ionic-framework, request

in parent component i got undefined value for data.
here is my code.

parentComponent.ts

```
testMethod(){
  console.log('t', this.answer.postRequest(this.quetion).subscribe(data => { 
    console.log('d',data);
  })); //here i got undefined value to data
}
```

serviceProvider.ts

```
postRequest(ques:string):Observable<any>{
  let header = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',"Accept":'application/json'
  });
  console.log(ques)

  return this.http.post(
    "http://localhost:8080/hello",
    {'q': ques},
    {headers: header}
  ).map(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, // this work fine and value is assigned to data as expected
  error => {(error);// Error getting the data});
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the http post request to `.map(data => data.json())`;

Comment: i tried. it says _property 'json' does not exist of type 'object'_. it marks by red line on code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/hello",{ 'q': ques },{ headers:header})
.map(data => { console.log(data); })
.map((resp: Response) => {return resp;});

it will helps

Comment: thaks dude that is helpful